# How to Get Access Log of Google Bucket via Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, access-log

I create a Bucket in Google Cloud Platform and publicly share some files. I want to  know the download log for these public files. However, in this document https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs , there are only 3 methods to get the log.

I try to use the first method, i.e. gsutils, by downloading and installing cloud SDK. However, due to the network blocking in China, gcloud cannot pass the initial connection test.

Therefore, I just wonder if it is possible to create and get access log via Google Cloud Platform Console(The document does not provide the method to do so). My browser can visit the console via a special proxy without any problems.

Thanks

Comment: Once in your console, can you open the Cloud Shell by clicking on the "Activate Cloud Shell" icon on the top right? If so you should be able to follow the instructions you mentioned from within your browser.

Comment: @LundinCast, Yes, I can. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully   reproduced  this scenario according to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs). The logs were created and I was able to download from the console. These were the steps that I performed:

1.- Open the Cloud Shell  by clicking on the button that is at the upper corner  on your panel with the symbol **">_"**.

2.-I ran the following command:  gsutil cp

Please let me know how it goes.